# Configuración de serenity : serenity.test.root

Tags: java

Intento saber que hace esta linea en Serenity

```
serenity.test.root=net.thucydides.showcase.cucumber.junit
```

ya he buscado pero no encuentro exactamente que hace esta línea de código

Comment: Hola revisaste la respuesta y documentación : https://serenity-bdd.github.io/theserenitybook/latest/junit-requirements.html#_modelling_requirements_in_junit

Answer (score -1):

Esto es especificado en la documentación, dentro de tu archivo `serenity.properties`, en `serenity.test.root=`  especificas el paquete raíz que estas usando, como ejemplo la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en este caso el paquete raíz (root package) se configuraría de esta forma:

```
serenity.test.root=net.serenitybdd.samples.junit.features
```

Revisa la documentación

[Modelling JUnit requirements](https://serenity-bdd.github.io/theserenitybook/latest/junit-requirements.html#_modelling_requirements_in_junit)